# Criação de código no pyhton

Tags: python

Olá gostaria de uma ajuda, preciso resolver a seguinte questão: Suponha que um caixa disponha apenas de notas de 1, 10 e 100 reais. Considerando que alguém está pagando uma compra, escreva um algoritmo que mostre o número mínimo de notas que o caixa deve fornecer como troco. Mostre também: o valor da compra, o valor do  troco e a quantidade de cada tipo de nota do troco. Suponha que o sistema monetário não utilize moedas.

Não entendi muito bem, alguem poderia me ajudar na realização do codigo. Conseguir fazer até aqui:

valor=int(input('----Informe o valor que o cliente deu:----'))

troco= valor - valor_compra

if (troco <10): >

--- Não sou muito bom em programação. Desde ja agradeço quem puder me ajudar :)

Comment: Se não consegue em Python, use "portugol", expresse a lógica usando português mesmo. Sua pergunta embute duas: elaborar o algoritmo, e codificar esse algoritmo em Python. Um problema de cada vez :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Olá Juliana!*

Se entendi bem, sua questão deve receber 2 valores de entrada:

- Valor do preço do produto comprado;
- Valor que foi pago pelo cliente.

Com os "inputs" (dados de entrada), temos 3 casos a considerar:

1. O valor pago pelo cliente é menor que o preço do produto;
2. O valor pago pelo cliente é igual ao preço do produto;
3. O valor pago pelo cliente é maior que o preço do produto.

Agora, basta fazer um programa que receba dois valores - pela função `input()`, como você já fez - e com base nos mesmos, utilizar condicionais `if()` para os 3 casos citados acima.

Logo, podemos iniciar o código da seguinte forma:

```
preco = int(input(' Digite o valor do preço do produto: ')) # Armazena na variável 'preco' o preço do produto, fornecido pelo usuário.
valor_pago = int(input(' Digite o valor pago pelo cliente: ')) # 'valor_pago' armazena o valor pago pelo cliente.

# Com isso, temos 3 casos a considerar, e associaremos os casos pelos condicionais if, elif e else:
if(valor_pago < preco): # Caso em que o valor pago pelo cliente for menor que o preço.
    print('\n O valor pago pelo cliente não é suficiente para a compra do produto.')
elif(valor_pago == preco): # Caso em que o valor pago é igual ao preço do produto. Utiliza-se 'elif' em casos de mais de duas condição.
    print('\n Troco ao cliente é de R$ 0,00.') # Utilizei '\n' para pular linhas no terminal.
else: # Caso o valor pago pelo cliente seja maior que o preço do produto (else), nenhum dos dois casos anteriores.
```

Em seguida, dentro do condicional `else`, deve-se aplicar a lógica para calcular a quantidade de notas de R$ 100, R$ 10 e R$ 1 que devem ser devolvidas ao cliente.
Para isso, utilizarei o operador `//`. Este operador é utilizado entre dois números, e retorna a divisão inteira entre eles. Conforme o exemplo abaixo:

`10 // 3 = 3`

`10 / 3 = 3,333333...`

Se deve ao fato de 10 / 3 ser igual a `3,3333...`, ou igual a 3 com resto 1. O operador `//` retorna apenas o resultado inteiro da divisão, descartando o resto.

Logo, no condicional `else`, farei uso desse operador, pois por exemplo:

`preco = 100`

`valor_pago = 250`

`troco = 150`

Caso queira a quantidade de notas de 100 (será apenas 1), basta fazer 
`notas_100 = troco // 100`, conforme descrito a seguir:

```
troco = valor_pago - preco # Calcula-se o troco.

notas_100 = troco // 100 # Calcula-se a quantidade de notas de R$100,00 a serem pagas ao cliente, pelo operado '//', que calcula a divisão inteira entre dois números.
print(f'\nNotas de R$100,00 para o cliente: {notas_100}') # Mostra ao usuário a quantidade de notas de 100, pela função print(f'{}').

troco = troco - (notas_100 * 100) # Diminui-se do troco a quantidade de notas de 100 multiplicadas 100.
notas_10 = troco // 10 # Mesmo método para notas de R$10,00.
print(f'Notas de R$10,00 para o cliente: {notas_10}')

troco = troco - (notas_10 * 10)
print(f'Notas de R$1,00 para o cliente: {troco}') # O troco restante está entre 0 e 10, portanto a quantidade de notas de R$1,00 é igual ao troco restante.
```

Creio que a explicação ficou um pouco complexa, porém a parte importante do código se baseia apenas no condicional `else`, mas é fundamental contar com os casos 1 e 2, visto que não é sempre que os usuários fazem uma digitação correta.

*Qualquer dúvida, estou à disposição :D*

*Att, Bruno Kenzo.*

Comment: Nossa muito obrigada, pode esclarecer muito bem minha dúvida, o inicio é facil a parte que dificulta é na lógica, mas sua explicação foi muito boa!!

Comment: De nada, Juliana!
Que bom ter ajudado hehe
To no começando na programação ainda, mas fazer uns exercícios assim ajuda bastante, né
Força!